# Table com input Radio como pegar o valor selecionado

Tags: javascript

Olá, eu tenho uma table que possui uma linha aonde é possível selecionar um radio button. Ao selecionar o button salvar eu quero pegar os valores que foram selecionados. Eu consigo pegar o texto do radio button, contudo não estou conseguindo pegar o valor selecionado.

insira o código

```js
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
        for (var i = 1,row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

          
            alert(cells[2].innerText);
        }
```

```html
         <tr>
             
                <td>
                  
                <label>
                    Presente
                    <input type="radio" name="@item.Id" value="1" checked>
                </label>

                <label>
                    Ausente
                    <input type="radio" name="@item.Id" value="0">
                </label>
                <td/>

            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o médoto **document.querySelectorAll** para procurar o elemento desejado. Ele irá retornar um array, como se trata de um input do tipo radio, você irá pegar apenas o elemento [0].

**input[type=radio]** - procura todos os elementos input do tipo radio

**:checked** - todos os input do tipo radio que estão selecionados

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')[0].value;
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked') retorna um array com todos os inputs selecionados, faça uma iteração utilizando for, while...